# Replace character that is not recognised by encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a large file that I'm trying to import. The file is made up of millions of row of customer created data. As such, some users have used characters that are not recognised by the encoding (less than 1 character per 100,000 characters).

However, this is causing the code to break, as it doesn't recognise the character, and giving me the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x96' in position 619: character maps to <undefined>
```

In the specific case above, the encoding doesn't recognise the long hyphen.

The code I am currently using to read the file, and conduct some transformation is:

```py
def conversion(path, source, count):
    file = open(path, "w")
    iFile = open(source, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    len_text = 1
    file.write("[\n")

    for line in iFile:                          # For all the lines in the file
        line = line.strip()                     # Remove newline/whitespace from begin and end of line
        line = line.replace('"newDetails":{','')
        line = line.replace('},"addrDate"',',"addrDate"')
        line = line.replace('},"open24Id"',',"open24Id"')

        if len_text != count:                   # While len_text does not equal line_count
            line+= r","                         # Add , to end of the line
            line+= "\n"                         # Add \n to end of line
            file.write(line)                    # Write line to file
        else:
            line += "\n"                        # Add \n to end of line
            file.write(line)                    # Write line to file

        len_text += 1                           # Increment len_text by 1

    file.write("]")                             # Write ] to end of file
    file.close()                                # Close file
    return
```

The break occurs on `file.write(line)`.

How can I tell the script to search for, and replace the character `\x96` with another character?

Comment: You can put a try at the bit that translates it, and while loop it so it keeps on the try so that the error is caught, then in the except you can remove or replace it.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Wouldn't a try, if it fails, skip the row?

Comment: The output file is encoded with your platform default, which in your case is some (Windows?) 8-bit codepage that doesn't support all characters (but it could be a different encoding if you run the script on another machine). Why not just use a universal encoding like UTF-8 for the output file as well?

Comment: If you absolutely must use an 8-bit encoding, you should specify it expclitly, and you can add an error handler that replaces unsupported characters, eg. `open(path, 'w', encoding='cp1252', errors='replace')`.

Comment: Btw, `'\x96'` is not an en-dash, but a control character. It looks like you might have garbled input already.

Comment: @lenz: The file comes into me, from an external vendor, in supposedly UTF-8. Will try your method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my comment:
A try will catch the errored part of the message, the except is how you deal with that, so if you said

```
try:
    your code
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    break
```

would skip it, but doing something like

```
try:
    your code
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    file.write("Your character")
```

That will allow you to use your code, and when it hits that error, it will replace it with the character you want to replace it with. Play with the code to change it to how you want it to work, I just did a generic example.

Comment: Has this helped you?

Comment: It has got me further along in the process. Finding new errors, so working through those. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help you.

Comment: If  you give me those errors, I can update the answer to try to fix it.